# nginx - adding custom header to upstream

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx to set some additional custom request headers to upstream. But it is not working (no headers are set). Any help would be appreciated.

```
location /someUrl {
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_set_header Test ABCDE;
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
}
```

Comment: What version of nginx?

Comment: @Shawn C. I am using version 1.14.0

Answer (score -1):

Try reversing the order the sets like :

```
location /someUrl {
   proxy_pass http://example.com;
   proxy_set_header Test ABCDE;
   proxy_pass_request_headers on;
}
```

I have seen this fix before but can not explain it has the documentation doesn't say anything.